# Delete AccountTeamMember

Tags: apex, integration, .net

We have .Net service which does CURD on account team members for a given Account. Whenever there is a change in the role of the members/person moved from one account to another, the service will perform a data sync to delete the Account team members. Now the question is how can .Net service can perform a delete on AccountTeamMember object.  As per my knowledge "IsDeleted" flag is not updatable.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_AccountTeamMember.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm

I am wondering how delete can be performed on this object. Could you please shed some light on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With spring 18 feature you could also delete multiple records(upto 200) in one go.

Use a DELETE request to delete to up 200 records, specified by ID, returning a list of DeleteResult objects. The objects in a DELETE request can belong to more than one object type. You can choose to roll back the entire request if there are errors.

/vXX.X/composite/sobjects/?ids=recordId,recordId

[Release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_api_rest.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To delete a record via REST, you use the DELETE verb:

```
DELETE /services/data/v45.0/sobjects/AccountTeamMember/{Id} HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.my.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer {sessionId}
```

On a successful result, you'll get a 204:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 06:09:27 GMT
```

For more information, you'll want to read about it in the [SObject Rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm) documentation.